# Can I ask for community advice as regards the final production version of my code; primarily to make sure security is solid?

Tags: discussion

Having been out of programming for quite a while; and this quite rusty, I have a question for S.O. meta.

I've built a new app, a variation on the Stripe Checkout snippet available online, and I'm wondering is it OK (and on a side note advisable?) to post the production code with a view to improving security/UIUX etc.

My client happens to be a good friend (i.e. I really want to do a good job); plus I hadn't actually planned on any programming here; the just ended up having to go that way; i.e. I'm a bit unnerved to release it and it's got a government grant to it etc etc? All to say lots of reason to get it right properly.

Anyway I have my (now working, thanks in no small part to Stack Overflow) code almost ready for either production or community discussion but hopefully I'd be able to get another set of professional eyes on, thanks.

Comment: Not here, without a specific problem, but that sounds the the right sort of thing for Code Review

Comment: I am not sure if your question is well suited for code review. But if you are going to ask there then I would suggest that you read through their [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page before posting.

Comment: Make sure that there is nothing personal in your code (such as private ip's, etc). I'm not an expert but I just wanted to warn you.

Comment: You're asking strangers on the internet to evaluate an app that you wrote for *security concerns*, and not a single one of us are obligated to get it right while you and you alone bear the ultimate responsibility of that app's fit for purpose. **Let that sink in.**

Comment: It's nice that you openly say "I get payed, you do the work"... but as @Makoto pointed out strangers on internet validating security for governmental contract... I understand that we live at the time that any PR is good but please don't involve SO into New York Times posts like "{Your country} government contacts outsourced to {most 'friendly' country} to review security" :)

Comment: [security.se] might also be relevant in that case

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire a software auditing firm, to be honest.

Comment: @Makoto, plenty of companies have made their software source available through a public repo with the express idea of good intentioned people looking for bugs and security concerns. I get that there are a lot of people who still are wary about this, but it generally seems to work. Especially when there's a reasonable code review process to prevent "some rando" putting in a backdoor or other bug/concern. I mean, it's apparently working for Linux and MS.

Comment: @Makoto your point is well taken, but having other programmers give your code even a cursory review is probably better than *not doing that*. I wouldn't use at a substitute for one's own due diligence (as I think you're trying to point out) but I don't think it'll hurt...

Comment: @computercarguy: [The same too was thought of OpenSSL when the Heartbleed bug was exposed.](http://web.archive.org/web/20190203160711/http://thecodelesscode.com/case/140)  Code as if *everyone* is the thief.

Comment: @JaredSmith:  I personally find it unacceptable because - again - you rely on the public to audit the code and be truthful to the level of the audit.  When you're talking about *security* - especially security in the satisfaction of a government grant - I would expect that's the fastest way to either lose that money or never qualify for it again if you don't do due diligence on actually vetting this code and getting that qualified.

Comment: @Makoto, nice story, but I found a couple of my own. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/do-bug-bounties-help-open-source-security/ and https://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/opinions/open-source-bug-bounty-1-1/ And don't forget that HeartBleed was not discovered by OpenSSL, but people outside the company. https://readwrite.com/2014/04/13/heartbleed-security-codenomicon-discovery/

Comment: Why not post the elements you want reviewed on [codereview.se]

Comment: @computercarguy: All of your examples are cases where an expert is *invested* in finding vulnerabilities: either she's using the software herself, or she's participating in a bug bounty program that pays her. That's not a coincidence; testing a program for security holes, or inspecting a non-trivial amount of code for that purpose, is a lot of work. Just posting your code on GitHub, or even on Stack Overflow, doesn't really get the necessary investment.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the just ended up"*?

Comment: You also need to realize that anything you post is posted using CC-BY-SA license.  You are releasing your code into the wild.  Anyone can use it for anything as long as they give you credit and promise to release their code similarly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license

Comment: Code improvement -> [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To all those suggesting [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) -- is a review on a complete (or nearly complete) application on topic for CR? Isn't CR meant for pieces of code -- a specific class or method or function?

Comment: @ruakh, if you read the articles, you'll notice that bug bounties aren't even the most significant part of why open source vulnerability location work. And who says the OP is against bug bounties? I gave articles where experts say that open source works, you are only giving your opinion why it might not. I'd rather believe industry experts than a comment on a forum.

Comment: @computercarguy: I'm not saying that open source doesn't work. It does. I'm just saying that "work" doesn't mean "magically accomplishes everything on its own with no further investment" — and nothing in your articles disagrees with me. (And I did read those articles before commenting, thank you very much, hence my being able to accurately describe them.)

Comment: @ruakh, I never said "open source magically fixes everything", as you imply. I also never said to "just post it". I said "other companies are seeing open source work for them, so consider it as a possibility", then gave examples of where and how it's working, and include bug bounties. You saying I did say those things does go against what I posted. Please, quit putting words into my "mouth".

Comment: @computercarguy: I'm not saying you said those things, and I'm sorry if I've made you feel like I am; I just feel that your comments provided a misleading perspective by showing successful examples without explaining what made them successful, thereby giving the impression that "just being open-source" was what made them successful. (Especially your first comment. Makoto hadn't argued against open-source, only against OP's approach being *sufficient*, and you seemed to be disagreeing, hence implying that it *is*.)

Comment: @ruakh, the way I read Makoto's comments and linked story is that he *is* against open source completely. That's what I based my comments on. It seems as if the thing we disagree on is what Makoto was trying to say. Reread his first comment and his response to JaredSmith to understand where I got my opinion. He doesn't say one thing good about open source in any of his other comments, either.

Comment: @computercarguy: OK, fair enough!